# How to center list-elements of DragDropList in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm trying to center the CDK-DragDrop List elements from angular-material.

I already tried to set the alignment and justified props but, they seem to get overwritten (even with !important) or just never read.

HTML section:

```
<div
  cdkDropList
  class="draglist"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="resortListAfterDrop($event)"
>
  <div
    class="interestField"
    *ngFor="let valuedInterest of valuedInterestList"
    cdkDrag
  >
    <p>
      {{ valuedInterest.getInterest().name }} <br />
      {{ valuedInterest.getPriority() }}
    </p>
  </div>
```

CSS style:

```
.interestField {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50%;

}
.cdk-drag-preview {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the selector more specific, e.g. `div.cdk-drag-preview`?